# How to validate user input in c?

Tags: c

I was wondering how would you go about validating user input in c, i need the user to input coordinates, a integer from (1-8) separated by another integer from (1-8), eg "1,1". I was wondering if i could do this either using strtok()or strtol()?

Answer (score 1):

If the input format is fixed, it is much simpler to use `fgets()` to get a line of input and then `sscanf()` to parse the input than to use `strtok()` and `strtol()`.

Here is an example that validates that the user enters two integers in the range [1, 8]. If the user enters fewer than two values, or if the values are out of range, or if there is extra input after the accepted values the user is prompted to enter another pair of coordinates.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[100];
    int x, y;

    /* sscanf() method: input must be comma-separated, with optional spaces */
    printf("Enter a pair of coordinates (x, y): ");
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
        perror("Input error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int ret_val;
    char end;
    while ((ret_val = sscanf(buffer, "%d , %d%c", &x, &y, &end)) != 3
           || x < 1
           || x > 8
           || y < 1
           || y > 8
           || end != '\n') {
        printf("Please enter two coordinates (x, y) in the range [1, 8]: ");
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
            perror("Input error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("You entered (%d, %d).\n", x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much